# How to convert a Maven Project to Spring REST Service

Tags: java, spring

I have 3000 lines of code which will perform copy the data from Excel and insert into MySQL db, and I written the code without spring framework. And everything looks fine but now I want to them as a Spring Boot REST service. If I call the endpoint URL It should return that the record is inserted as response message if not according to the code It should say "No record inserted."

I will post the sample code base below to get an idea that what I have tried so far.

```
package com.online.amazon.asinhunt.feature;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.online.amazon.asinhunt.dto.DBCloneDTO1;

public class GITJapi {

    @DataProvider(name = "data")
    public static Object[][] getVAlueFromExcel() throws Exception {
        HSSFSheet sheet = TestJapi.getActiveSheet();
        Object[][] dataObj = new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()
                - JDBCUtils.getRecordCounts(38)][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
        boolean isCondition = false;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {

                row.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                if (JDBCUtils.getRecordCounts(38) < i) {

                    System.out.println(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());

                    isCondition = true;

                    dataObj[count][j] = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();

                }

            }
            if (isCondition == true) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return dataObj;
    }

    public static HSSFSheet getActiveSheet() throws Exception {

        File f = new File(
                ".//testOCT_US.xls");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
        fis.close();
        return sheet;

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "data")
    public static void insertRecords(String rowNu, String testcaseId,
            String description, String priority, String buyer,
            String transactionData, String dbValidation) throws Exception {

        DBCloneDTO1 setValueToPojo = new DBCloneDTO1(rowNu, testcaseId,
                description, priority, buyer, transactionData, dbValidation);

        JDBCUtils.insertQuery(setValueToPojo);
        System.out.println("Cloned successfully....");

        System.out.println(description + "\t Description.....");

    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void cleanUp() throws Exception {
        boolean condition = isDeleteDirectory(new File(".//clone1//"));
        if (condition) {
            Sysout("");
        }

    }


    public static boolean isDeleteDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory.exists()) {
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            if (null != files) {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                        isDeleteDirectory(files[i]);
                    } else {
                        files[i].delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (directory.delete());
    }

}
```

The above Java file is executable one which has @Test annotation and there was a lot of calls in this file which is just POJO and replica of Excel and Backend. The whole code purpose to insert the record into back end which is available in Excel sheet.

Now I need to convert this whole project in a single REST Call. If I hit REST spring end point URL It should call above class and return an OK message or data inserted message as output.

Comment: I can't figure out what specific problem you are having when doing this. Make a simple Spring REST service, and in the controller call this class's methods. You can start with any basic Spring REST tutorial for a basic controller setup.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I'm new to spring world. But I have to deliver the functionality as REST spring boot service. gone through docs which is available. but I'm totally confused now. don't know how can I easily convert the above project as spring services.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is "totally confusing" you. Have you tried to implement the Spring Boot REST tutorial? https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ What specific issue did you encounter?

Comment: I just created a main class which has springbootapplication and the above code I annotated as RestController and @Test method I used as RequestMapping("\").  and tried to ran the main class but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is really easy to do that, you need to take in mind .this things, first as a rest .api you will add a "controller" this is in order to add the necessaries endpoints, .the your actual code will be part of a "service" the services will have the business logic that you need in this case will be the excel logic. (Second thing is not a good practice return the object that you are using in the services layer so you will need a transform object to do that. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Thanks It makes sense.